# why does adding the glimpse nuget package cause my mvc3app not to startup..?

Tags: .net, glimpse

Glimpse looks v cool/exciting, but installing it via nuget, made 
my application fail to start ( 'resource not found') 
(as though somethings's going on with routing?)
I can access the /Glimpse/Config/  page ok..

but my actual app isnt starting..

the config has been left as per nuget install.

i.e. under `<configSections>` I have:

```
<section name="glimpse" type="Glimpse.Net.Configuration.GlimpseConfiguration" />
```

and under `<configuration>` I have:

```
<glimpse on="true" saveRequestCount="5">
    <ipAddresses>
      <add address="127.0.0.1" />
      --><!--IPv4--><!--
      <add address="::1" />
      --><!--IPv6--><!--
    </ipAddresses>
    <contentTypes>
      <add contentType="text/html" />
    </contentTypes>
</glimpse>
```

does anyone know if this some standard newbie issue...? (e.g. is it actually supposed to work in cassini..?)
are the config settings ok..?
anyone know what's wrong here..?

thanks,

J.

Comment: Have you copied the config wrong? There are a few too many comments in there (`<!--`). Also, have you tried using IIS Express?

Comment: This configuration is no longer valid in [Glimpse 1.0](https://nuget.org/packages/Glimpse/).

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have an syntax error in the .config file. Try replacing with this:

```
<glimpse on="true" saveRequestCount="5">
    <ipAddresses>
      <add address="127.0.0.1" />
      <!--IPv4--><!--
      <add address="::1" />
      --><!--IPv6-->
    </ipAddresses>
    <contentTypes>
      <add contentType="text/html" />
    </contentTypes>
</glimpse>
```

Comment: Glimpse has a new simplified configuration.  All you need now is <glimpse enabled="true"/>

Answer (score 0):

@Jay are you using any custom route providers or anything like that. Also if you create just a basic solution in your environment do you get the same issue?